# PDF Orientation Ignored on Brother QL1060 with RHEL6

Tags: linux, printing, redhat, rhel

We are working on migrating our application server from our existing RHEL 4 server to RHEL 6.  The application will print via cups a PDF output file to the printer, and usually this doesn't cause us any issues.  On one specific printer type - Brother QL1060n - the orientation seems to be ignored.  On the same printer, if going from Windows XP/7, it will maintain the print output orientation.  Off of our RHEL 6 server - it ignores it.  The command we're using to simulate and test is:

```
lp -d brotherql1060 -o landscape filename.pdf
```

Our other printers - HP's, Konicas, Oki, etc, all seem to print the same file without issue using the same command - however the Brother units will ignore the landscape argument and print portrait.  We tried printing portrait, and it will print exactly the same.

We are using the latest driver from Brother's website.  We also tried the older driver from the RHEL 4 platform, and when we try that, nothing prints - the job leaves the queue, but the printer does nothing.

We also updated the printer firmware to the latest version -and no change to the behavior.

So far Google-fu has yielded a few ideas, but no solutions.

Comment: I was able to us the `-o landscape` option to print the label in landscape with my Brother QL-570 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Facing same issue... Prints landscape with "-o landscape" for .txt file... but not with .pdf file..  Did you find solution for it ?